# Implementation of Prim's algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

Could anyone comment on what could be done better and if I made any mistakes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

typedef pair<pair<int, int>, int> Edge; //a, b, length
// A---------B
//   length


vector<Edge> prims_algo(vector<vector<int>> graph, int number_of_nodes){
    vector<int> unvisited;
    vector<int> visited;
    vector<Edge> result;

    //mark first as visited and mark the rest as unvisited
    for (int i = 1; i < number_of_nodes; i++)
        unvisited.push_back(i);
    visited.push_back(0);

    while (!unvisited.empty()) {

        vector<Edge> edges_with_lengths;
        //put all edges (with their lengths) from nodes that are in visited
        for(auto node : visited) {
            for (int sec_node = 0; sec_node < number_of_nodes; sec_node++) {
                if (graph[node][sec_node] > 0 && find(unvisited.begin(), unvisited.end(), sec_node) != unvisited.end()) {
                    //add if there is connection and second node is not visited yet
                    Edge e = make_pair(make_pair(node, sec_node), graph[node][sec_node]);
                    edges_with_lengths.push_back(e);
                }
            }
        }

        //find the shortest edge
        pair<pair<int, int>, int> the_shortest;
        the_shortest = edges_with_lengths.front();
        for(auto i: edges_with_lengths){
            if(the_shortest.second > i.second)
                the_shortest = i;
        }

        //add the shortest path to the result
        result.push_back(the_shortest);

        //remove a node that the shortest edge leads to
        unvisited.erase(remove(unvisited.begin(), unvisited.end(), the_shortest.first.second), unvisited.end());

        //mark this node as visited
        visited.push_back(the_shortest.first.second);
    };
    return result;
}


int main() {
    /*
       2    3
   (0)--(1)--(2)
    |   / \   |
   6| 8/   \5 |7
    | /     \ |
   (3)-------(4)
         9          */
    vector<vector<int>> graph =
                     {{{0, 2, 0, 6, 0},
                       {2, 0, 3, 8, 5},
                       {0, 3, 0, 0, 7},
                       {6, 8, 0, 0, 9},
                       {0, 5, 7, 9, 0},
    }};

    vector<Edge> result = prims_algo(graph, 5);
    for(auto i:result){
        cout<<"EDGE [ " <<i.first.first<<", "<<i.first.second<<"], length: "<<i.second<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Code looks OK.

I would suggest you to do some class instead of `Edge`:

```
//typedef pair<pair<int, int>, int> Edge; //a, b, length
struct Edge{
   int a;
   int b;
   int length;
};
```

Also I suggest to have some predefined type for `vector<Edge>`

```
using EdgeContainer = vector<Edge>;
```

You have duplication near `//find the shortest edge`, you probably need `Edge` there

Here `the_shortest` is probably not initialized. Also you probably might use something from `<algorithm>` (but I will do it in same way as you).

```
    //find the shortest edge
    pair<pair<int, int>, int> the_shortest;
    the_shortest = edges_with_lengths.front();
    for(auto i: edges_with_lengths){
        if(the_shortest.second > i.second)
            the_shortest = i;
    }
```

Another probably `micro optimization` would be to write `++i` in loops:

```
//for (int i = 1; i < number_of_nodes; i++)
for (int i = 1; i < number_of_nodes; ++i){
   // ...
}
```

Also in `C++11` `main()` does not need to `return 0;`.

Comment: "Another probably micro optimization would be to write ++i in loops" For this case (integer or other primitive type), there is no optimization gain at all. For user-defined types, you are correct: postincrement involves a copy to be made, whereas preincrement doesn't. So prefer ++i for user-defined types, and then continue to use it for primitive data types if the choice between pre- vs post- increment doesn't matter, for code consistency.

Comment: fully agree, but i think is good habit to use it as ++i

Comment: Agreed, hence the last part of my comment, "continue to use it for primitive data types ... for code consistency"

Answer (score 2):

Consider naming the function for *the result it produces* rather than *the algorithm used*.  The user of the function generally doesn't care how the result is found, and will not mind if we change to a different algorithm in future versions, as long as it returns the minimum spanning tree of the input nodes.

Avoid `using namespace std;` - that's a very large (and changing) namespace, and it's much safer and clearer to use qualified names where you need them.

We are missing an include of `<utility>` for the use of `std::pair`.  That said, the nested pair looks like a candidate for `std::tuple` or, more likely, a `struct` with proper names for its elements.

The function doesn't need to modify the contents of `graph`, so there's no need to make a copy; we should pass by const-ref instead.  Do we really need the `number_of_nodes` argument?  I think that's just the inner vector's length.

We could use `std::iota` instead of a loop to populate `unvisited`:

```
#include <numeric>

    unvisited.resize(number_of_nodes - 1);
    std::iota(unvisited.begin(), unvisited.end(), 1);
```

Similarly, for finding the shortest edge, we could use `std::min_element()` instead of our own loop.  Or we could keep track of the minimum as we examine the lengths, instead of populating a vector and then searching it.

I think that a `std::set` would be a more suitable storage for `unvisited`.  That would enable more efficient membership test and removal.  The `result` and `visited` vectors can be given sufficient capacity for the number of elements they will hold at the end using `reserve`.

---

Here's what I get after making these improvements:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

struct Edge
{
    // A---------B
    //   length
    int a;
    int b;
    int length;
};

std::vector<Edge> minimum_spanning_tree(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& graph)
{
    std::set<int> unvisited;
    std::vector<int> visited;
    std::vector<Edge> result;

    auto const number_of_nodes  = graph.size();

    // mark first as visited and mark the rest as unvisited
    visited.reserve(number_of_nodes);
    visited.push_back(0);
    for (auto i = 1u;  i < number_of_nodes;  ++i)
        unvisited.insert(i);
    result.reserve(number_of_nodes - 1);

    while (!unvisited.empty()) {
        Edge the_shortest = { -1, -1, INT_MAX };
        //put all edges (with their lengths) from nodes that are in visited
        for (auto node: visited) {
            auto const& lengths = graph[node];
            for (auto sec_node = 0u;  sec_node < lengths.size();  ++sec_node) {
                auto const length = lengths[sec_node];
                if (length > 0 && length < the_shortest.length
                               && unvisited.count(sec_node)) {
                    // our new closest node
                    the_shortest = {node, (int)sec_node, length};
                }
            }
        }

        //add the shortest path to the result
        result.push_back(the_shortest);

        // mark the destination as visited
        unvisited.erase(the_shortest.b);
        visited.push_back(the_shortest.b);
    };
    return result;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    /*
       2    3
   (0)--(1)--(2)
    |   / \   |
   6| 8/   \5 |7
    | /     \ |
   (3)-------(4)
         9          */
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph =
                     {{{0, 2, 0, 6, 0},
                       {2, 0, 3, 8, 5},
                       {0, 3, 0, 0, 7},
                       {6, 8, 0, 0, 9},
                       {0, 5, 7, 9, 0},
    }};

    auto result = minimum_spanning_tree(graph);
    for (auto const& i: result) {
        std::cout << "EDGE [ " << i.a << ", " << i.b << "], length: " << i.length << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have not used a priority queue, so performance is not good.

Comment: While this states [one observation about the code in question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that looks valid, your post could be more helpful: What implementations of a `priority queue` would be advantageous? Which specific part of the code would profit? What is the impact of this improvement on overall/asymptotic performance? You are welcome to share more insights, advice, and opinions.